# GCC Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I have a `char* pointer` and when I do `(++pointer)= NULL`, there's an error:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it? The code is

```
void func(const char*p1, const char *p2){
    char * pointer;
    pointer=malloc(strlen(p1)+strlen(p2)+2;
    (++pointer)=NULL;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of incrementing a pointer and subsequently set it to NULL?

Comment: Did you mean `*pointer = '\0';`?

Comment: You've accepted an answer even though it's not clear from you post what you intended to accomplish in the line `(++pointer)=NULL;`.

Comment: "I have a `char *` pointer" - So yu have a `char **`! And you loose the anchor. Remember to `--p` before `free`! But what do you think is the last line supposed to do anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol `pointer` is an lvalue and can be used in an assignment on the left hand side.  `(++pointer)`, however, is not an lvalue and cannot be used in the same assignment.

If on an alien planet far far away it did compile, this code would increment pointer by one and then set it to zero (`NULL`) so to achieve the same effect, and be portable to earth compilers, use `pointer = NULL;`

Comment: It will never compile.

Comment: Edited to stress the hypothetical

Answer (score 2):

The subexpression `(++pointer)` will evaluate to an *rvalue* and it can't be a left operand of assignment (`=`) operator.

Answer (score 2):

Some expressions cannot be an `assignable l-value`.

In your code `(++pointer)` is an expression, which cannot be used as a left operand of the `=` sign.

---

Think of something like

```
(x + 2) = 5  // (x + 2) is an expression
```

Does it makes sense?

Comment: Some expressions are assignable lvalues, for example `*(p + 1)`. It's just that not every expression designates a modifiable location in memory.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev, Thanx. Edited